# Series Convergence of $1/(1+x)$

Tags: calculus, power-series

For what $x$ does $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^k x^k$ converge (to $1/(1 + x)$) or diverge? Or does it converge within an interval like $\left[-1, +1\right]$?

Comment: Is there supposed to be an $n$ or $k$ somewhere? As it's written, it's just a function.

Comment: Do you mean to ask "does the series $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^k x^k$ converge to $1/(1 + x)$?" It doesn't really make sense to ask whether a rational function converges.

Comment: $1/(1+x)$ is not a series, do you mean its Taylor series expansion?

Comment: Do you mean the Taylor series for that function, centered at $x=0$?

Comment: 1/(1+x) = 1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + ... is a series. And it becomes geometric if x is substituted by -x

Comment: I've edited the question to what I think you wanted to ask. If it's not what you intended, feel free to change it.

Comment: I am asking geometric series (1/(1-x)) converges only if |x| < 1. Is there any equivalence for (1/(1+x))?

Comment: @user81301 Just change $x$ in $-x$.

Comment: $1/(1 - x)$ isn't a geometric series, it's just a function.

Comment: I think all calculus book says 1/(1-x) is a geometric series but I think I have got an answer from imranfat. Thanks imran.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}x^k$ is the Taylor series for $1/(1 - x)$, and we can tell that it converges for $x\in \left(-1,1\right)$ by the [ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) (separate, but not difficult, analysis works at the endpoints). So, if we would expect that $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left(-x\right)^k = 1/(1 + x)$ on some interval (perhaps also $\left(-1,1\right)$). We can find when this series converges (and hence, when the value is the same as the value of $1/(1 + x)$) by the ratio test again, and we find the same results: $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left(-x\right)^k$ converges (to $1/(1 + x)$) for $x\in\left(-1,1\right)$.

Comment: Just note that $|x|<1\iff |-x|<1$.

Answer (score 1):

By the [alternating series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test), $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^k x^k$ converges, when $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^k = 0$. This is obviously the case, when $|x| < 1$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the author means the Taylor expansion of the given expression. That converges for all x between -1 and 1 (boundary values excluded)